# Reduction of order higher order ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Solve : $(x+2)\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}-(2x+5)\frac{dy}{dx}+2y=(x+1)e^x$.

[image: method of reduction of order of Higher order ode]

Can anyone please explain that how do we come to know $y = e^{2x}$ makes left hand side of given equation to zero in the first place? Is there any technique?

Comment: Please use image processing software to rotate images and reduce the resolution to a readable minimum. I did that for you here. Also, write at least parts of the task in text/mathjax, as images do not appear in the topic lists.

Answer (score 1):

You can try a factorization of the left side. 
$$
L[y]=(x+2)(y''-2y')-(y'-2y)=((x+2)D-1)(D-2)y=0
$$
where $D=\frac{d}{dx}$. This is obviously zero if $(D-2)y=y'-2y=0$ which has the mentioned solutions $y=Ce^{2x}$.

**Remarks**

This approach will not work in general, the example was constructed such that this factorization exists.

You could also exchange the factors using $D((x+2)u)=(x+2)Du+u=((x+2)D+1)u$ to
$$
L[y]=(D-2)((x+2)D-2)y.
$$
The factor equation $((x+2)D-2)y=0$ is of the Euler-Cauchy type and has solutions of the form $(x+2)^m$, here with $m=2$.

You can use the factorizations to split the equation into two easy first order stages, introducing intermediate functions $u=(D-2)y$ or $v=((x+2)D-2)y$, respectively.
$$
\left.\begin{aligned}
(x+2)u'-u&=0\\
y'-2y&=u
\end{aligned}\right\}
~~\text{ or }~~
\left\{\begin{aligned}
v'-2v&=0\\
(x+2)y'-2y&=v
\end{aligned}\right.
$$